# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I run into this error today, the code is:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = [
    1, 7, 0, 0, 6, 8, 1, 8, 0, 5, 4, 2, 2, 8, 8, 4, 5, 4, 8, 3, 1, 8, 0, 1, 9,
    7, 5, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 5, 8, 1, 4, 4, 5, 7, 4, 5, 2, 4, 2, 4, 7, 8, 5, 0
]

plt.figure(15, figsize=(15, 7))
pos = {}

for i in range(0, len(l)):
    pos[i] = (i, l[i])

X = nx.Graph()
X.add_nodes_from(pos.keys())

for i in range(0, len(l) - 1):
    X.add_edge(i, i + 1, weight=1, label='I')

for n1, p in pos.items():
    X.node[n1]['pos'] = p

labeldict = dict(zip(range(0, len(l)), [str(i) for i in l]))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(X, pos, node_size=200, node_color='orange')
nx.draw_networkx_labels(
    X, pos, labels=labeldict, font_size=14, font_family='sans-serif')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(X, pos, width=1, edge_color='g')
plt.show()
```

But I never run into this error with similar code befor, could someone tell me how come the error?

The full error is:

```
 Exception in Tkinter callback
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 22, in blit
     id(data), colormode, id(bbox_array))
 _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "PyAggImagePhoto"
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in __call__
     return self.func(*args)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 283, in resize
     self.show()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 355, in draw
     tkagg.blit(self._tkphoto, self.renderer._renderer, colormode=2)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 26, in blit
     _tkagg.tkinit(tk.interpaddr(), 1)
 OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t
```

Comment: The code is extract from my program, but the program working well.

Comment: this code does not currently raise the error for me. Either way, please post the traceback message you receive when getting the error.

Comment: I add the Traceback.

Comment: You did but the error is still not reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems t the problem come out of TkAgg backend, I try add:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
```

before

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Unexpected all's working fine.

Comment: This is why we request a [mcve].  It takes time and effort for people to read your code and think about the problem.  You should do as much as possible to make sure the person doing this is at least using code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: It seems the code doesn't reproduces the problem for you, you know the code works  in general. Maybe that's a matplotlib  bug.